# Is it possible to check if onSnapshot() has found changes before actually fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I am navigating to a page, I am passing some parameters such as "*Discounts*" and I am displaying that number in the `render()` but I am calling `onSnapshot()` right in the begin of navigating to that class. Now, I would like to display in the begin ONLY the value of the parameter and in case there are changes fetch it.

P.S. the reason behind this is that I am trying to reduce the number of fetches as much as possible.

```
 check_amount_left() {
    const getSelected = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    var ref = db().collection('discounts').where("rest_id", "==", getSelected.rest_id)
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
        var amount = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().amount);
        this.setState({
            check_for_amount: amount.toString()
        });
    }));
}
```

**Render method:**

```
render(){
  const getSelected = this.props.navigation.state.params;
   return(
     <View>
       {getSelected.amount}
     </View>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know that something changed about data on the server, the server will need to tell the client about that change. In the case of Firestore the server always tells the client the entire new state of the document.

So the only way to reduce the amount of data that the server sends to the client, is to reduce the size of the document you're listening to.

But event then, it would not reduce the number of fetches, as the server will need to read the document to know that it has changed.

Comment: thanks for the answer Frank! So, does this mean that using onSnapshot() to listen for changes at a specific field, will cost me the same as if I am fetching the entire document?

Comment: You can't listen for a specific field, you can only listen for entire documents. The cost for a document read is the same not matter the size of the document, but of course for a smaller document you will see less bandwidth cost.

Comment: how can I calculate the bandwidth cost? couldnt find it in the Firebase site

Comment: You'll have to estimate the size. Or (since you're on web) you can get a pretty good idea by checking the network tab in your browser.

Comment: No, my app is built on React-Native. Estimate the size? Is there a price for mb/gb of transaction?